# How to pass a VPC's ID as a parameter to the Cluster.template to set as a default value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to find a way to set default VPCs, Subnets and Security Groups in the Cluster.template JSON file.

Is there a way to pass an existing VPC ( or Subnet/Security group) as a parameter to the template using the "Ref" built-in?

This Obviously dones't work:

```
 "Parameters": {
    "VpcId": {
       "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
       "Default": { "Ref" : "vpc-123456789" },
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it's really much simpler than I thought... this worked:

```
 "Parameters": {
    "VpcId": {
       "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>",
       "Default":  "vpc-123456789,vpc-987654123" ,
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To inject a VPC id into your template I would do the following. First remove your default value.

```
"Parameters": {
    "VpcId": {
       "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
....
}
```

Next place the value you want to set VpcId to inside a parameters.json file and when you perform a create-stack or update-stack using your cloudformation use the parameters file as the input.

**parameters.json**

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "VpcId",
    "ParameterValue": "vpc-123456789"
  }
]
```

**Multi-valued Parameters**

If you had a parameter that takes a list of values you could represent it as follows

```
"PrivateEC2Subnets": {
  "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
  "Description": "List of private subnets to run your EC2 instances inside. Note that they must be in the same availability zone that your ELB is configured for. May require you to manually create a private subnet with a specific AZ if your VPC isnt auto-configured."
},
```

Then in your external parameters file pass in a comma separated list like so

```
  {
    "ParameterKey": "PrivateEC2Subnets",
    "ParameterValue": "subnet-9934670a544,subnet-d74ea349f"
  },
```

For more information on the different parameter types see the AWS doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html but beware, people have reported issues when trying to represent lists of complex datatypes in external parameters files. To my knowledge, only CommaDelimitedList works if you want to pass the values in from another json file outside your cloudformation template.

Comment: What if I had two values to add to the same attribute?

Comment: @VardaElentári I just added an example that uses multiple values just now.

Comment: @VardaElentári No problem. If it ends up working feel free to mark this as the accepted answer for future users.

Comment: So, unfortunately, that didn't work. I tried `"Default" : "sg-12334234"` and that worked for auto-populating one attribute, but when doing that for two attributes it didn't work using the type `CommaDelimitedList`. But I'll upvote anyway.

Comment: @VardaElentári With the solution I listed you shouldn't set a default. You only define the parameter type then get the value from the external parameters file. What error message did you get that says its not working?